# Conditional rendering animation effect

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a tab component where the user can switch between brand and model. Is it possible to add a smoothing or an effect when changing the component that is being shown? I'm finding it too dry, with no effect, when the user changes the tab.

[image]

code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-darkness-bfijv?file=/src/App.js&fbclid=IwAR2diVKlb4fGrkjCmnR8Lq5IaPAB9GiiVrL5Vepz_LLNlNXAO-_gL1-NVNg

Answer (score 0):

You could add a css keyframes animation to your data.

To do that, give your `div` that wraps your data a `className`. I named it `className="data"`.

Then in your css:

```css
.data {
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-pateu-bbsld?file=/src/styles.css:396-411